# How can I align my flexbox elements and make them the same size?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm just starting out using Flexbox and having a little bit of trouble figuring out how to do what I'd like.  Ultimately I'm trying to build a nice looking "control panel" / HUD.  Here's what I have so far https://jsfiddle.net/1req8u25/.

And reproduced here

```css
#sliders-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #333333;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.slider-container {
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.slider-label {
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: small;
  color: white;
  flex: 0 0 40%;
}

.slider {
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}

.slider-value {
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: small;
  color: white;
  flex: 0 0 10%;
}
```

```html
<div id="sliders-container">
  <div class="slider-container">
    <p class="slider-label">foo</p>
    <input class="slider" min="0" max="100" type="range">
    <p class="slider-value">10</p>
  </div>
    <div class="slider-container">
    <p class="slider-label">foo-bar-baz</p>
    <input class="slider" min="0" max="100" type="range">
    <p class="slider-value">0</p>
  </div>
    <div class="slider-container">
    <p class="slider-label">quuuuuuuuuuuuux</p>
    <input class="slider" min="0" max="100" type="range">
    <p class="slider-value">0.0000001</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This produces

[image]

Which obviously looks bad.  What I'd like is for each row to take up all necessary space in order to fit everything inside of it, for each left label to be the same size, for each slider to be the same width, and for each right label to be the same size.

Is that possible?

Comment: If you want your elements to align both horizontally and vertically, you could look at CSS Grid instead of Flexbox.

Answer (score 1):

You can use css grid for that.

```
    .slider-container {
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  /* flex: 0 0 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center; */
}
```

replacing the flex content for

```
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
```

grid-template-columns says the size of each column, in this case 1fr means 1 part of the current space.

for align the last labels on the right, you can use the same tags from flexbox,
inside .slider-value put:

```
justify-self: end;
```

it will align the text on the right side.

https://jsfiddle.net/6pz7sjxq/3/

Answer (score 0):

First, your total container width is too small. Same goes for each section (10% might not be enough for the `slider-value`.

I'd also replace the `p` with `div` since it's not a paragraph you're wrapping with the tag and you don't need it to have vertical space.

```css
#sliders-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #333333;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: flex-start;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 400px;
}

.slider-container {
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.slider-label {
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: small;
  color: white;
  flex: 0 0 30%;
}

.slider {
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}

.slider-value {
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: small;
  color: white;
  flex: 0 0 20%;
}
```

```html
<div id="sliders-container">
  <div class="slider-container">
    <div class="slider-label">foo</div>
    <input class="slider" min="0" max="100" type="range">
    <div class="slider-value">10</div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider-container">
    <div class="slider-label">foo-bar-baz</div>
    <input class="slider" min="0" max="100" type="range">
    <p class="slider-value">0</p>
  </div>
  <div class="slider-container">
    <div class="slider-label">quuuuuuuuuuuuux</div>
    <input class="slider" min="0" max="100" type="range">
    <div class="slider-value">0.0000001</div>
  </div>
</div>
```